# Integration of $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ function

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have trouble calculating an integral of $f(x,y)=(x-y,2x+2y)$ over $\Omega=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x|+|y|\leq1\}$.

I calculated the boundaries which will be $\Omega=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: |y|\le 1-|x|\,,\,|x|\le 1\right\}$.

I don't know how to calculate an integral of $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ function. Any help?

Comment: You just integrate each component separately. That is, integrate both $x-y$ and $2x+2y$ over $\Omega$, and your answer is the ordered pair of these two integrals.

Comment: Draw a picture of $\Omega$ in the plane!  Important!! Useful!!!  Helpful!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to symmetry, the integral of the odd integrand $f(x,y)$ over a centered square vanishes. To actually carry out the integral, let $x=\frac1{\sqrt2}(u+v)$ and $y=\frac1{\sqrt2}(u-v)$. Then
$$\iint_\Omega f(x-y, 2x+2y)dxdy =\sqrt2 \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 
(v,2u)dudv=0$$

Comment: I have calculated it slightly different way but also got $0$ as and answer. Thanks!